# Сортировка по убыванию или возрастанию значений с плавающей запятой в массиве данных

Tags: python, pandas, сортировка, dataframe

Как сортировать по убыванию или возрастанию где число 1,023,222 считалось бы больше чем 200,333?
А также если перед числом стоит $1,023,222?

Я попробовал сделать так:

```
price_list = []    
for index, row in top_us_2022.iterrows():
    price = str(row[3])
    price_n = price.replace('$', '').replace(',', '').replace('nan', '0')
    price_int = int(price_n)
    price_list.append(price_int)
price_list.sort()
```

Но как это сделать в рамках ВСЕЙ таблицы, а не одного столбца?
(то есть сортировка по этому столбцу, читая всю таблицу)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: *где число 1,023,222 считалось бы* Это НЕ число.

Comment: А да? Числа разделенные запятыми извините пожалуйста..

Comment: И если перед числом будет $, то тогда это тоже будет **не** число... `где число 1,023,222 считалось бы больше чем 200,333` - а разве оно уже не больше?

Comment: sort_values сортирует только по первому числу как я понял

Comment: понятно что это не число вопрос в другом в каком методе или функции есть параметры чтобы убрать допустим символы  и посчитать эти числа как единые

Comment: str.replace запятые и знак доллара на ничто

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так, как уже и подсказали в комментариях - заменой лишних символов:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Total Gross': [
        '$1,000,000',
        '$500,000',
        '$200'
    ],
    'Order': [
        1,
        2,
        3
    ]
})

df['for_sort'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Total Gross'].str.replace(r'[$,]', '', regex=True))
df.sort_values('for_sort')
```

Вывод:

| index | Total Gross | Order | for_sort |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | $200 | 3 | 200 |
| 1 | $500,000 | 2 | 500000 |
| 0 | $1,000,000 | 1 | 1000000 |

Я использовал `to_numeric`, потому что непонятно на выходе будут целые значения или с плавающей точкой, эта функция с обоими вариантами должна нормально справиться.

Comment: Спасибо! Работает